# Deleting all end tags with no start tag

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013, replace

I am editing many pages of aging HTML in VS 2013. I can make part of the edit easily, using Find/Replace All, but this leaves me with a end tag with no start tag. Is there a way I can remove all the end tags with no start tags. Seems like there should be since intellisense sees them.

Original code example:

```
<h2 class="chapter"><a class="anchor-name" id="foo">This Chapter Title</a></h2>
```

What I have after find change all:

```
<h2 class="chapter" id="foo">This Chapter's Title</a></h2>
```

What I want to get to:

```
<h2 class="chapter" id="foo">This Chapter's Title</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a VS2013 available, but this should be doable with a regex replace operation.
Assuming you want to remove the `<a class="anchor-name" id="foo">` and `</a>` tags, your search should be: `<a class="anchor-name" id="foo">(.+)<\/a>` and replace by: `$1`
Like this (on VS2017)
[image: Regex values set on Find and Replace box]

With some tweaks on the regex, you should be able to alter it for other class values.